# XLConnect cloneSheet error

Tags: r, xlconnect

Using R (R 3.3), `XLConnect` package V 0.2.12, `rJava` package V 0.9.8, receiving error.

> Error: IllegalArgumentException (Java): Sheet index (-1) is out of range (0..3)

When I run clonesheet function.  Below is the code for the workbook:

```
wb <- loadWorkbook(paste0("C:\\Users\\james.keane\\Documents\\R\\RETC R 
    Scripts\\Client Progress Report\\", fileName, separate = ""), create = 
    TRUE)
setStyleAction(wb,XLC$"STYLE_ACTION.NONE")        # This allows the 
     spreadsheet to be populated with data without chaninging the formating 
     of the spreadsheet

# Check to see if sheet exists
tabNames <- getSheets(wb)
if(length(grep(taxSeason, tabNames)) >= 1){
     writeWorksheet(wb, paste(taxSeason, "Property Tax Appeal Status", 
         separate = " "), sheet = taxSeason, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, 
         header = FALSE)
     writeWorksheet(wb, reportClient[,1:22], sheet = taxSeason, startRow = 
         3, startCol = 1, header = FALSE)
     writeWorksheet(wb, reportClient[,28:33], sheet = taxSeason, startRow = 
          3, startCol = 28, header = FALSE)
}else{
     cloneSheet(wb, "Template", taxSeason)
     writeWorksheet(wb, paste(taxSeason, "Property Tax Appeal Status", 
         separate = " "), sheet = taxSeason, startRow = 1, startCol = 1, 
         header = FALSE)
     writeWorksheet(wb, reportClient[,1:22], sheet = taxSeason, startRow = 
         3, startCol = 1, header = FALSE)
     writeWorksheet(wb, reportClient[,28:33], sheet = taxSeason, startRow = 
         3, startCol = 28, header = FALSE)
}
saveWorkbook(wb)
```

Once the workbook is saved and the file is opened I'll have the following tabs:[image of tabs after code run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6QEc.png)

Before the code is run, there are only the three tabs "Exhibit A", "Template", and "Data Validation".  Once the code is run, it should clone the Template tab, rename it to the appropriate taxSeason year, and then this new sheet is populated with data using the `writeWorkSheet` function.

There have been times that it has worked and others it doesn't so not sure why it's going back and forth.  Any ideas on why this is occurring?